# How to check if an individual datatable row is empty or not?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, dataset, datarow

So in this dataset I want to check for the number of boys and number of girls and the total . The dataset returns `Table[1]` which has two rows, number of girls and number of boys .The `row[0][1]` returns the number of girls and the  `row[1][1]` returns the number of males 
[image]

but whenever the `Table1` returns single row .ie count of either boys or girls , an `IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown `There is no row at position 1` at the first `if` itself.

Is my way of checking for empty datarow correct?

And here is the code snippet

```
 if (dsStudent != null && dsStudent.Tables.Count > 0 && dsStudent.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!(dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[0]==null) && !(dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[1]==null)) //both are present
            {
                lblbNumOfGirls.Text = dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[0][1].ToString().Trim();
                lblNumOfBoys.Text = dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[1][1].ToString().Trim();
            }
            else if ((dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[0][1].Equals(string.Empty))) //if girls are 0
            {
                lblbNumOfGirls.Text="0";
                lblNumOfBoys.Text = dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[1][1].ToString().Trim();
            }

            else //if boys are 0
            {
                 lblNumOfBoys.Text="0";
                 lblbNumOfGirls.Text = dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[0][1].ToString().Trim();
            }

            lblNumStudents.Text = (int.Parse(lblNumOfBoys.Text) + int.Parse(lblbNumOfGirls.Text)).ToString(); //total number of students
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Table1` returns only 1 row, the index of that 1 row is "0". That;s why you are getting `Index out of bound` issue.

If you are only running the code when there are two rows or more (one row for male and one row for female and other), your check should be `dsStudent.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 1`

Because your check was `dsStudent.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0`, your code will enter the if-statement when there is only 1 row, but throw a exception when you are trying to access the second row `dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[1][1].ToString().Trim()`

Remember, count and index is different in coding.

```
Row 1: index = 0
Row 2: index = 1
Row 3: index = 2
...
```

**-- EDIT--**

Okay, I see. So the problem is that you are reading `Table1`, but did not varify it first.

This is the line where it's throwing exception:

```
if (!(dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[0]==null) && !(dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[1]==null))
```

You are reading `Rows[0]` and `Rows[1]`, but it is possible that the row doesn't exist.

For example, if your table only contains 1 row, the second part of the condition `dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[1]` will throw exception because `Rows[1]` doesn't exist.

To check if your table contains at least two rows, the easiest way is to do this:

```
if (dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows.Count >= 2)
{
}
```

My suggestion is to check for boys and girls within inside the if-statement.

And also, if the value is null, you can not compare it with `String.Empty`

`NULL` does not equal to `String.Empty`

```
if (dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows.Count >= 2)
{
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[0][1])) //girls = 0
    {
    }
    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(dsStudent.Tables[1].Rows[1][1])) //boys = 0
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting two rows when both girls and boys are present.Only when either one of them is present I get single row

Comment: @saurabh64 please see my updated answer, I'm guessing that you are confused with count and index.

Comment: Table[0] is a separate table and Table[1] is separate .Everything related to Table[0] is working fine